# MySQL - Aggregating information from two tables

Tags: mysql, join

I struggling to bring summarized figures from one table into a working query with aggregated data already.

I'm attempting to compare the sub-totals of overtime worked vs overtime quoted

The overtime quoted query is as follows:

```
SELECT
    workorder_entry.workorder_id AS 'Work Order #',
    DATE_FORMAT((internalinvoice.invoice_date), '%b %e %Y') AS 'Invoice Date',
    SUM(ROUND((workorder_entry.adjusted_hours)*(workorder_entry.quantity),2)) AS 'Overtime Charged'
        FROM workorder_entry

        INNER JOIN service
        INNER JOIN servicecategory
        INNER JOIN internalinvoice  
        ON workorder_entry.service_id = service.ID
        AND service.servicecategory_id = servicecategory.ID
        AND internalinvoice.workorder_id = workorder_entry.workorder_id

        WHERE internalinvoice.invoice_date > CAST('2015-06-01 00:00:01' AS DATE)
        AND internalinvoice.invoice_date < CAST('2015-07-01 00:00:01' AS DATE)
        AND (workorder_entry.adjusted_hours)*(workorder_entry.quantity) >0
        AND servicecategory.ID <> 443

    GROUP BY internalinvoice.workorder_id
    ORDER BY internalinvoice.invoice_date ASC;
```

The above returns a list of all jobs that were invoiced in the date range specified with a summary of the overtime hours for specific services (ie. not 443).

The output looks like:

```
Work Order #  | Invoice Date  |   Overtime Charged  
37755         | Jun 2 2015    |       10.16  
37754         | Jun 2 2015    |       18.00  
37753         | Jun 2 2015    |       25.00
```

Now I want to add a 4th column that is the total of all overtime hours worked on the work orders above.  These are listed in the jobcost_timesheet_entry table which looks like the following (dates are repeated as more than one person may be working on a job at the same time):

```
workorder_id |Date Worked|   overtime  
37755        |May 15 2015|      9.50  
37755        |May 16 2015|      0.00  
37755        |May 17 2015|     12.25  
37755        |May 17 2015|      0.00  
37755        |May 17 2015|      1.75    
37755        |May 18 2015|      4.00
37754        |May 20 2015|      0.00
37753        |May 29 2015|     10.25
37753        |May 30 2015|      1.50
```

Desired output:

```
Work Order #  | Invoice Date  | Overtime Charged  |Overtime Worked | Difference
37755         | Jun 2 2015    | 10.16             | 27.50          |     -17.34
37754         | Jun 2 2015    | 18.00             |  0.00          |      18.00
37753         | Jun 2 2015    | 25.00             | 11.75          |      14.25
```

I've tried several different things none of which was remotely close to the correct information.  I suspect the answer may be a sub-query on the second set of data but I'm a bit lost at this point and multiple searches here didn't really provide good direction for a situation such as this.

I'd much appreciate any assistance

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding an aggregate groupby subquery as a derived table (see `job_ot_total`).

```
SELECT 
    workorder_entry.workorder_id AS 'Work Order #', 
    DATE_FORMAT((internalinvoice.invoice_date), '%b %e %Y') AS 'Invoice Date'
    SUM(ROUND((workorder_entry.adjusted_hours)*(workorder_entry.quantity),2)) AS 'Overtime Charged',
    job_ot_total.SumOfOT AS 'Overtime Worked',
    (SUM(ROUND((workorder_entry.adjusted_hours)*(workorder_entry.quantity),2)) -
        job_ot_total.SumOfOT) AS 'Difference'
FROM workorder_entry
INNER JOIN service 
INNER JOIN servicecategory
INNER JOIN internalinvoice 
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT j.workerorder_id, Sum(j.overtime) AS SumOfOT
        FROM jobcost_timesheet_entry j
        GROUP BY j.workerorder_id
        ) AS job_ot_total
   ON workorder_entry.service_id = service.ID 
  AND service.servicecategory_id = servicecategory.ID 
  AND internalinvoice.workorder_id = workorder_entry.workorder_id  
  AND workorder_entry.workorder_id = job_ot_total.workerorder_id

WHERE internalinvoice.invoice_date > CAST('2015-06-01 00:00:01' AS DATE) 
  AND internalinvoice.invoice_date < CAST('2015-07-01 00:00:01' AS DATE) 
  AND (workorder_entry.adjusted_hours)*(workorder_entry.quantity) >0 
  AND servicecategory.ID <> 443

GROUP BY internalinvoice.workorder_id 
ORDER BY internalinvoice.invoice_date ASC;
```

Alternatively, save `job_ot_total` as a view and incorporate it into main query. There is many [forum and blog discussions](http://www.google.com/search?q=database+view+vs+derived+table) debating which is more efficient, readable, and maintainable: view vs derived table.

```
SELECT j.workerorder_id, Sum(j.overtime) AS SumOfOT
FROM jobcost_timesheet_entry j
GROUP BY j.workerorder_id
```